# Windows Batch file to run in background and kill any non responsive program automatically

Tags: batch-file, process, thread-safety, background-process, windows-7-x64

I am using an application which keeps hanging and makes my computer non responsive, at this point i won't be able to open task manager or do anything else. I have to hard reboot my system.

I came across some batch command which can kill non responsive programs.

```
taskkill /f /fi "status eq not responding"
```

I am aware of how to create a batch file.

Can anyone suggest how to always run this batch command in background and hunt those programs which are not responding?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Batch programs were never designed run in the background in windows.  They always simply execute through once.

What I have done for this type of scenario is setup a windows scheduled task to run every X minutes where X is an appropriate interval to check for the process in your environment.

Hope that helps!

Comment: if my program has caused the computer freeze, well at that time, will scheduler still execute that task?

Comment: Unknown. You should be able to always get control of your computer (in theory anyway). If you can't then maybe task scheduler can't either. Have to try it. You could use the `timeout` command in a always running batchfile (or if you don't like the window a vbscript).

Comment: Yeah, its going to depend in the case of a freeze.  Doesn't sound like a very safe program, I'm guessing this is on a desktop and not any kind of server.

Comment: @RyanMcArthur appication is on windows desktop, but keeps interacting with the server

Comment: @bgalea i am not sure what a timeout command is? could you please share some link or something?

Comment: In a command prompt type `timeout /?`. Type `help /?` for a list of common commands. All of them can be `command /?`. Some newer commands have subcommands so `reg /?` and `reg query /?`. To access task scheduler - `schtasks /?` or `schtasks /query /?` (not the inconsistency sometimes `/` sometimes not). So set a label (`:MyLabel` then your taskkill command, then `timeout` then `Goto MyLabel`. Note Use the imagename as Not Responding just means the program hasn't picked up messages from windows for 5 secs.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Scheduled Task to run periodically in Windows. Lookup Windows Task Scheduler.

Another way is to  launch this batch file and run this command in an infinite loop. Ex

```
:start
taskkill /f /fi "status eq not responding"
sleep 600
goto start
```

this will run the command every 10 minutes.

Comment: `sleep` is not a native command in Windows command prompt; use `timeout /T 600 /NOBREAK` instead...

Comment: Agreed. But sleep.exe has been part for MS eco system for so long, I do not know of any version of windows that does not include it.